# Merge 2 files with past in Shell - line break /carriage return \n problem

Tags: shell, file, merge, carriage-return

I want to merge two files with each line:

fichier1.txt:

```
1;2;3
4;5;6
7;8;9
```

fichier 2.txt:

```
a;b
c;d
e;f
```

I want to have the file  fichierfusionné.txt looks like this :

```
1;2;3;a;b
4;5;6;c;d
7;8;9;e;f
```

Here is the code that i have :

```
paste -d ';' {fichier1,fichier2}.txt > 'fichierfusionné.txt'
```

With this code my file fichierfusionné.txt contains :

```
1;2;3
;a;b
4;5;6
;c;d
7;8;9;e;f
```

I don't know how to solve the problem,
is there any option to avoid \n  ?

Could you help me ?

Comment: Check your line-endings. Unix expects `\n`. If `od -c` shows `\r \n`, you have DOS line-endings. You can convert with `dos2unix`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk` is one way to deal with different types of newlines.

This will make the ouput to have Linux `\n` line endings.

```
awk 'FNR==NR {arr[FNR]=$0; next}{print arr[FNR],$0}' RS='(\r\n|\r|\n)' OFS=';' fichier1.txt fichier 2.txt > 'fichierfusionné.txt'
```

This one will use DOS-style `\r\n` line endings.

```
awk 'FNR==NR {arr[FNR]=$0; next}{print arr[FNR],$0}' RS='(\r\n|\r|\n)' ORS='\r\n' OFS=';' fichier1.txt fichier 2.txt > 'fichierfusionné.txt'
```

And lastly, MAC `\r` line endings.

```
awk 'FNR==NR {arr[FNR]=$0; next}{print arr[FNR],$0}' RS='(\r\n|\r|\n)' ORS='\r' OFS=';' fichier1.txt fichier 2.txt > 'fichierfusionné.txt'
```